# Spring AOP not working on Spring SOAP Web Service

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-ws

I have a spring soap web service and i want to use custom logging aspect to measure its performance. The aspect is working fine for normal spring beans but not getting called for Endpoint-invokeInternal method. Is there any restriction in spring for same like protected method...? Appreciate any help to get it working?

Code Sample:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class AspectLogging {

    @Around(value = "execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(logTime)", argNames = "logTime")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, LogTime logTime) throws Throwable {
            // Time logging goes here...
    }
}
```

Spring Context:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/> 
<!-- Aspect -->
<bean id="aspectLog" class="com.x.y.AspectLogging" />
```

Spring WS Endpoint:

```
public class MyEndPoint extends AbstractJDomPayloadEndpoint {
    @LogTime
    protected Element invokeInternal(Element request) throws Exception {
        // Service call goes here...
    }
}
```

Update:
It worked after changing access modifier to public, does this mean Spring allows AOP to be applicable only for public methods?

Answer (score 0):

> Update: It worked after changing access modifier to public, does this mean Spring allows AOP to be applicable only for public methods?

Spring AOP knows two ways of creating dynamic proxies:

- JDK dynamic proxies: This is the default but only works for interfaces (or Spring components classes implementing them) and only proxies the public methods defined in those interfaces.
- CGLIB proxies: This has to be activated via `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>` (or an equivalent config annotation) which you already did and works for both interfaces and classes. So if you have a class implementing an interface you can expect only public methods defined in that interface to be proxies just like with JDK proxies. It depends on how you define the type of your Spring bean, I guess. Make sure to really instantiate the class type, not the interface type. Then protected or package-scoped methods should also be proxied by CGLIB (just not private methods). So if done correctly, this should work.

I am not talking about you using a deprecated base class with equally deprecated methods here, just answering your question...